# createEvent with Visibility=Private

Tags: google-apps-script

I have basic Google Apps script code like this:

```
myCal.createEvent( eventName, startDate, endDate );
```

Where the variables are basic string and datetime variables. No issues there.

In addition, I'd also like to create this event with `Visibility` set to `Private`. I can see this option per calendar event on the interface, but I don't see any documentation on this in `createEvent`.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

There is a setVisibility method in the CalendarEvent object.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#setVisibility(Visibility)

createEvent() has a return type of CalendarEvent.

```
 myCal.createEvent( eventName, startDate, endDate )
     .setVisibility(CalendarApp.Visibility.PRIVATE);
```